# Can't disable Periodically if not otherwise run in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile, I want to disable the Scan Multibranch Pipeline Trigger: "Periodically if not otherwise run", but I can't find solution for Jenkins version 2.164

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in Organization Folder configuration, we sould add a Build strategies: 
None Strategies Match: None of Regular branches

After the config, the job inside doesn't run automatically every day.